# How to ensure I have exactly 2 spaces before string and zero spaces after

Tags: bash

I get a string that can have from zero to multiple leading and trailing spaces.

I'm trying to get rid of them without lot of hackery but my code looks huge.

How to do this in a clean way?

Comment: can the string contain spaces appart from trailing and leading ones?

Comment: sure, it may contain lot of "between" spaces

Answer (score 5, accepted):

as easy as:

```
$ src="      some text          "

$ dst="  $(echo $src)" 

$ echo ":$dst:"
:  some text:
```

`$(echo $src)` will get rid of all around spaces.
than you simply add how much spaces you need before it.

Comment: `$(echo $src)` does the trick, i like it! very concise and stable

Comment: It will munge any internal spaces. If you're fine with that, the `echo` in backticks is superfluous. I would recommend against this approach.

Comment: To demonstrate, you can replace the last line with `echo :" " $src:` for the same effect. If you have `src='one  two'` with two spaces, one of them will be lost.

Answer (score 1):

How are you calling out the string? If it's an echo you can just put

```
Echo "<2 spaces>". "string";
```

if it's a normal string you just put 2 spaces between the first qoute and the string.

```
"<2spaces> string here"
```

Answer (score 1):

One way using `GNU sed`:

```
sed 's/^[ \t]*/  /; s/[ \t]*$//' file.txt
```

You can apply this to a bash variable like this:

```
echo "$string" | sed 's/^[ \t]*/  /; s/[ \t]*$//'
```

And save it like this:

```
variable=$(echo "$string" | sed 's/^[ \t]*/  /; s/[ \t]*$//')
```

Explanation:

The first substitution will remove all leading whitespace and replace it with two spaces.
The second substitution will simply remove all lagging whitespace from a line.

Comment: I wouldn't hesitate to call `sed`

Answer (score 1):

The simplest is probably to use an external process.

```
value=$(echo "$value" | sed 's/^ *\(.*[^ ]\) *$/  \1/')
```

If you need to transform an empty string into two spaces, you'll need to modify the regex; and if you're not on Linux, your `sed` dialect may differ slightly. For maximum portability, switch to `awk` or Perl, or do it all in Bash. That gets a bit more complex, but for a start, `trailing=${value##*[! ]}` contains any trailing spaces, and you can trim them off with `${value%$trailing}`, and similarly for leading spaces. See the section on variable substitution in the Bash manual for details.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expression to match everything between the leading and trailing spaces. The matched text is found in the `BASH_REMATCH` array (the text matching the first parentheses group is in element 1).

```
spcs='\ *'
text='.*[^ ]'
[[ $src =~ ^$spcs($text)$spcs$ ]]
dst="  ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
```